# Footnote overlapping with page number

Tags: footnotes, longtable, page-numbering, overlap

I found a similar question in the forums but I think my case is a bit different. I'm using the `geometry` and `fancyhdr` packages to write my thesis. There is a place where I have to insert a long table (using the `longtable` package), and there is a footnote in that page. When I compile, the page number is overlapping with the text of the footnote.

I'm having trouble obtaining the `MWE` because my project has a main body into which I input the different parts. I've taken the whole thing and stripped it down to its bare bones, but it turns out the problem disappears when I do that:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish, french]{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{Partie \thechapter}
\fancyhead[LE]{Meurtre au centre-ville : la révolution d'Armero}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\usepackage[
    left = \flqq{},% 
    right = \frqq{},% 
    leftsub = \flq{},% 
    rightsub = \frq{} %
]{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,ibidpage=true,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Mibiblioteca.bib}
\nobibliography{Fuentes.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph}

\FrenchFootnotes

\usepackage{endnotes}

\title{
{Meutre au centre-ville : la révolution d'Armero\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\large Colombie, avril 1948}\\
{\large Université Sorbonne Nouvelle - Paris 3}\\
}
\author{Santiago Giraldo Arango}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{onehalfspace}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\part{Sociabilité, religion, violence et politique}

\chapter{\textit{¡A la carga!}}

\section{\textit{La Violencia} : mise à jour des guerres civiles du $\textsc{XIX}^{e}$ siècle ?}

\section{Révolution au féminin}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{Articles volés au café Los Balcanes le 9 avril 1948}\\
\hline
\textbf{Produit} & \textbf{Prix} & \textbf{Total} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ } \\
\hline
\textbf{Produit} & \textbf{Prix} & \textbf{Total} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
8 douzaines de cigarettes Camel & \$ 4,20/douzaine & \$ 33,60 \\ 
6 douzaines de cigarettes Chester & \$ 4,30/douzaine & \$ 28,80 \\  
9 douzaines de cigarettes Lucky & \$ 4,30/douzaine & \$ 38,70 \\   
4 douzaines de cigarettes Kool & \$ 4,30/douzaine & \$ 17,20 \\
9 1/2 paquets de cigarettes Pielroja & \$ 29,50/paquet & \$ 280,25 \\
150 cigarettes Últimos & \$ 9,00/centaine & \$ 13,50 \\
100 cigarettes Villamizar & \$ 5,50/centaine & \$ 5,50 \\
7 boîtes de batteries & \$ 13,00/unité & \$ 91,00 \\
17 bouteilles Alhucema & \$ 12,00/douzaine & \$ 17,00 \\
60 barres de savon Palmolive grand & \$ 5,00/douzaine & \$ 25,00 \\
24 barres de savon Palmolive moyen & \$ 3,50/douzaine & \$ 7,00 \\
49 barres de savon Renter & \$ 6,30/douzaine & \$ 25,72 \\
4 douzaines de boîtes de sardines Portuguesas & \$ 10,80/douzaine & \$ 43,20 \\
3 douzaines de boîtes de sardines Salmonete & \$ 4,00/douzaine & \$ 14,40 \\
21 boîtes de thon & \$ 15,00/douzaine & \$ 26,25 \\
3 douzaines de boîtes de saucisses & \$ 9,00/douzaine & \$ 27,00 \\
5 cartons d'Alka Seltzer & \$ 4,20/unité & \$ 21,00 \\
9 cartons de Mejoral & \$ 0,80/unité & \$ 7,20 \\
6 pots d'insecticide Whiz & \$ 0,85/unité & \$ 5,10 \\
1 set de boules de billard & & \$ 120 \\
3 boîtes de raisins secs & \$ 3,60/unité & \$ 10,80 \\
1/2 paquet de peignes pour cheveux & \$ 0,70/douzaine & \$ 4,20 \\
1 thermos pour café & & \$ 5,50 \\
1 régulateur de tension & & \$ 40,00 \\
3 boîtes de galettes de soda [sic] & \$ 3,60/unité & \$ 10,80 \\ 
4 boîtes de viande bœuf & \$ 1,20/unité & \$ 4,80 \\
3 paquets d'allumettes El Rey & \$ 6,30/unité & \$ 18,30 \\
1 montre de table & & \$ 10,00 \\
12 bouteilles d'\textit{aguardiente} & \$ 1,90/unité & \$ 22,80 \\
15 bouteilles de liqueur à l'anis & \$ 2,30/unité & \$ 34,50 \\
1 1/2 bouteilles de whisky & \$ 35,00/unité & \$ 52,50 \\
3 boîtes de rasoirs Gillette & \$ 5,00/unité & \$ 15,00 \\
1 bonbonnière & & \$ 10,00 \\
1 comptoir & & \$ 70,00 \\
1 enseigne lumineuse & & \$ 20,00 \\
1 vitrine pour cigarettes & & \$ 6,00 \\
1 tabouret & & \$ 5,00 \\
& & \textbf{\$ 1 122,12}\footnote{\cite[feuillet 64]{noauthor_inventario_1948}.} \\
\end{longtable}

\section{Avril radiophonique}

\part{Le village des assassins}

\part{La cage flexible}

\part{Conclusion}

\end{onehalfspace}

\part{Annexes}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Santiago

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. What is your document class? Where is your `longtable` environment defined? All sorts of other problems.

Comment: Please post the `MWE` as in error free format...

Comment: Thank you for your replies. 

The document class is `report`.

I'm not sure how to go about getting the MWE because my project has a main body into which I input the different parts. I just made a copy of the project and stripped it of all the non-relevant information. However, the problem disappears when I do that, so it probably has more to do with the exact place where I want to insert it in the document.

Comment: I just edited the question to include the `MWE`

Comment: Does the example in the question really exhibit the problem for you? There is one footnote, but as far as I can see its text is far away from the page number. (I realize I don't see the same text in the footnote as you, as I would need the file Mibiblioteca.bib for that. You really should just type some text in the footnote in the example instead and remove the biblatex stuff which hardly is relevant to display the problem you have.)

Comment: No, the example does not exhibit the problem. In the main project, I realized the problem has disappeared as I continued working on the document. However, I still notice that the page number is way to close to the text in the footnote in the specific page where I'm placing the long table. Also, this is a table that spans more than one page, that's why I chose the `longtable`package.

Sorry for being a noob but, what do you mean by "remove the biblatex stuff"? Which part of the code are you refering to?